# passing parameters in http GET using angular 2

Tags: angular

How do i send parameters in GET call using angular 2
I tried in the following way, but getting some error saying,

```
Argument of type '{ params: URLSearchParams; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestOptionsArgs'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'params' does not exist in type 'RequestOptionsArgs'.
```

function call:

```ts
import {Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions, URLSearchParams} from 'angular2/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

 constructor(private nav: NavController, public http: Http) {
    onLogin(value: string): void { 
        if(this.authForm.valid) {
          this.userData.login();
          let params = '';
          let options = new RequestOptions({
              // Have to make a URLSearchParams with a query string
              params: new URLSearchParams('validateUsr=false')
          });
          this.http.get('https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topmovies/limit=1/json', options)
          .map(res => res.json())
          .subscribe(
            data => {},
            err => this.logError(err),
            () => this.validateUser()
          );

          this.nav.push(AccountViewPage);
        }
      }
```

Need to pass the parameres like this,

```js
params: {
   validateUsr: "false"
}
```

Answer (score 24):

If you want to send query parameters within a GET request, use the `search` attribute instead of the `params` one:

```
constructor(private nav: NavController, public http: Http) {
}

onLogin(value: string): void { 
    if(this.authForm.valid) {
      this.userData.login();
      let params = '';
      let options = new RequestOptions({
          // Have to make a URLSearchParams with a query string
          search: new URLSearchParams('validateUsr=false') // <-----
      });
      this.http.get('https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topmovies/limit=1/json', options)
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(
        data => {},
        err => this.logError(err),
        () => this.validateUser()
      );

      this.nav.push(AccountViewPage);
   }
}
```

Comment: in case you are wondering where to retrieve URLSearchParams from:
import { URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';

Comment: what if i have an JS param object??

Comment: @Toolkit Take a look at my answer below if you want to pass a JS param object. The JS params object can't be used directly in the GET request, but it can be used to build up the params object that can be used.

Comment: why use search attribute instead of params?

Answer (score 11):

[Thierry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37292510/4367226) is great, but in case folks are looking to create a function that can accept a JS object of params to be passed, I wanted to add an expanded option. In the following function, `data` is an optional JS object of key/value pairs that can be passed to the function. It will then be iterated over and each key/value pair will be added to the `URLSearchParams` helper object (`params`). Once the params object is built up, it can be handed off to the GET request as the `search` property under the `RequestOptions` object (`options`).

```
handleGet(service:string, data?:any):Observable<any[]> {
    let params = new URLSearchParams();
    for(let key in data) {
        params.set(key, data[key]);
    }
    let options = new RequestOptions({
        search: params
    });
    return this._http.get(service, options)
        .map(this._extractData)
        .catch(this._handleError)
        .finally(() => {
            // do something...
        });
}
```